# Static Electromagnetic fiels

Tags: electrostatics, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

What is the mathematical proof that static electric and magnetic fields are independent of each other?

Comment: Independent in what sense? Maxwell's equations show they follow separate equations.

Comment: Adding to what @Avantgarde is saying, just set the time derivatives of the fields in Maxwell's equations to $0$. And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's equations (outside of a medium) are:

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$$

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0\mathbf{J} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

In the static case, $\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t} = 0$, so these reduce to

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = 0$$

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$$

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0\mathbf{J}$$

Now it's plain to see that $\mathbf{E}$ depends only on the net charge density $\rho$, and $\mathbf{B}$ depends only on the current density $\mathbf{J}$. In the general case (i.e. without further constraints), there is no relationship between the net charge density and the current density, just as there is no relationship between the position and velocity of a free particle in classical mechanics (this is more than just an analogy - the net charge density describes the position of charges, and the current density describes their velocity). However, if, in a particular physical situation, there **are** additional constraints that impose a relation between charge density and current density, then the electric and magnetic fields will be correspondingly related.